# jQuery mobile pages not loading correctly after servlet redirect

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

I have some pages in my mobile web app based on **jQuery Mobile** that need to be accessible without authentication and some only after user has been authenticated.  My solution is based on this tutorial: [Java Servlet Filter Example Tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/1933/java-servlet-filter-example-tutorial).

I have done **@WebFilter** which checks to which page user tries to access and if he isn't authenticated (**session** not created or there isn't attribute **user** inside the **session**) he's being redirected to **login.html** page.

This is relevant code from my **login.html** page:

```
<form action="LoginServlet" method="post">
...
input elements for username and password
...
</form>
```

Form submitting its data to **LoginServlet**. **LoginServlet** checks that credentials are correct and if they're correct, redirect it back to the required page. Currently I store required page in the session ([it's better to store this in a hidden element inside the form, but I didn't know it when I was writing the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1921327/947111))

I perform redirect from **LoginServlet** by using this line of code:

```
response.sendRedirect(redirectToPage);
```

All pages in my project are simple ***.html** pages with **javascript**, I make a mobile web app by using **jQuery Mobile**.

My problem that after redirect to required page:

1. It the address bar I see name of the my servlet, **LoginServlet** while in a console of Chrome I didn't see content of my page, only the name of my servlet, **LoginServlet** and its content is a blank. But inside the browser I see all static content, it's rendered correctly.
2. The most important problem that all my dynamic content in a loaded page doesn't work. Dynamic content I mean a few **ajax** function which should be invoked upon page loading and render dynamic content:

   ```
   $(document).on('pagebeforeshow',function(){
               initPage();
   });
   ```

If I reload page everything begins to work as it should.

What am I doing wrong? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: To downvoter - at least you could specify the reason, so I could know what's wrong with my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually a two solutions for this problem. 
The first one is to perform redirect in **javascript** not in servlet, and I think that it's preferable solution, for more details look here: [How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)
And second solution if you required to do it from **servlet** after submitting a `<form/>`, is to add `data-ajax="false"` into the `<form/>` tag: 
`<form action="postthis" method="post" data-ajax="false">`, this solution is taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8631895/947111